# R - subsets of matrix gives incorrect dimension

Tags: r, matrix, subset, dimension

I'm a newbie regarding R, but after struggling with this problem for quite some time I'm searching for help:

I have a matrix:

```
> is.matrix(Ls)
[1] TRUE

> Ls
       Start        Duration
       newrow_fin "1014507296" "133.313"
       newrow_fin "1014657293" "449.975"
       newrow_fin "1015523823" "566.614"
       newrow_fin "1017473690" "233.236"
```

And I would like to subset this matrix into 3 other matrices:

```
> int2_start
 [1] 1014174109
> int3_start
 [1] 1016639945
Ls1<-subset.matrix(Ls, (Ls[,1])<=int2_start) [,c(1,2)]
Ls2<-subset.matrix(Ls, (Ls[,1])>int2_start) [,c(1,2)]
Ls2<-subset.matrix(Ls2, (Ls2[,1])<=int3_start)  [,c(1,2)]
Ls3<-subset.matrix(Ls, (Ls[,1])>int3_start) [,c(1,2)]
```

It works fine for Ls1 & Ls2. But Ls3 changes format.

```
> Ls1
 Start Duration
> Ls2
       Start        Duration
       newrow_fin "1014507296" "133.313"
       newrow_fin "1014657293" "449.975"
       newrow_fin "1015523823" "566.614"
> Ls3
   Start     Duration
       "1017473690"    "233.236"
> is(Ls1)
[1] "matrix"    "array"     "structure" "vector"
> is(Ls2)
[1] "matrix"    "array"     "structure" "vector"
> is(Ls3)
[1] "character"           "vector"              "data.frameRowLabels" "SuperClassMethod"
```

I don't get it.

Comment: You have any numeric in your matrix. Only characters.

Comment: If I change the code to Ls2<-subset.matrix(Ls, as.numeric(Ls[,1])>int2_start) [,c(1,2)]. Same problem

Comment: It should be something like `LS <- as.numeric(LS)`

Comment: The search is working, however the change in dimension (Ls1&Ls2 compared to Ls3) is what is causing my problem.

Answer (score 0):

By default `[` selections try to simplify the result by dropping dimension with length 1. Add `drop = FALSE` if you don't want that.

```
test <- array(1, dim = rep(2, 3))
dim(test) # 3 dimensions
dim(test[1, ,]) # 2 dimensions
dim(test[1, 1,]) # 1 dimension
dim(test[1, , , drop = FALSE]) # 3 dimensions
dim(test[1, 1, , drop = FALSE]) # 3 dimensions
```